# Fetching image using image path stored in database

Tags: php, mysql

The below code only shows the present uploaded image.How can i fetch all the images using the path stored in the database

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if($link)
{
 $filetemp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
  $filepath="uploaded/";
  $location=$path.$filename;
  move_uploaded_file($filetemp,$location);
  $query=mysqli_query($link,"call imageInsert('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')");
  if($query)
  {
    echo "Image inserted successfully...";
  }
  else
  {
   echo "Insertion Failedd!!!";
  }
   echo '<img width="250" height="250" src= "'.$location.'"/>';
}
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Where is `$path` defined ?

Comment: Do a select query and get your path from there and use that in the img src

Comment: what table is "imageInsert" procedure modifying? just do `select * from <table> where filepath like '$filepath'` then iterate on returned array using `foreach`.

Comment: sorry it was $filepath

Comment: i have tried to use the path from the database but images are not displaying.Even i stored the full path

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$filepath="uploaded/";
$location=$filepath.$filename; # its filepath not path
```

And if image upload fail `echo '<img width="250" height="250" src= "'.$location.'"/>';` will not work.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($filetemp,$location))
{   
    # this `mysqli_query` not valuable to use on here, Because you're already in same function
    # $query=mysqli_query($link,"call imageInsert('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')");
    echo "Image inserted successfully...";
    echo '<img width="250" height="250" src= "'.$location.'"/>';
}
else
{
    echo "Insertion Failedd!!!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have used the code below to uploading the images,saving the relative paths
into database and fetching all the images together

```
     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    { $host = "";
   $db_name = "";
     $username = "";
   $password = "";
$link=mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$filetmp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$target="uploaded/".$filename;
$image_url="http://holo-com.stackstaging.com/uploaded".$filename;
$sql="INSERT INTO images (name,image_url) VALUES   ('$filename','$image_url')";
 mysqli_query($link,$sql);
 if(move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$target)){
  echo "Image uploaded";
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Failed to upload";
   }
  }


?>

      and for fetching the images

      $link=mysqli_connect($host,$db_name,$password,$username);
  $sql="SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC ";
  $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);


  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $image[] = $row;
 }


  foreach($image as $brand){

    echo"<img src='uploaded/".$brand["name"]."'width=33%,height=33%>";

 }
```